# Why we take vertical displacement as $A\sin(κx-ωt)$ not $A\sin(ωt-κx)$?

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, conventions

A general form of wave equation is

$$Y = A \sin(ωt-kx+φ)$$

Now if $t = 0$ is taken at the instant when the left end is crossing the mean position from upward to downward direction, $φ = π$ and the equation will be
$$Y = A \sin(kx-ωt)$$

now the above equation is taken to prove the frequency of standing wave why we dont take previous equation ($A \sin(\omega t - kx)$), if we take the previous equation the result is bizarre. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "prove the frequency"?   What result is bizarre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Physicists like to keep $k$ with a positive sign because we very very frequently work with single frequency fields, in which case time derivatives become constants.  For example
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \rightarrow -\omega^2$$  Our interest then is the spatial distribution, and it's convenient to not have that minus sign in front of $k$.

Engineers typically deal with time-varying fields (not constant frequency) and are usually not interested in the spatial distribution.   For them it's more convenient to keep $\omega$ with a  positive sign.

Engineers are more likely to use your first form, physicists the second.  But this is hardly universal.    It's a matter of taste for the author.

Answer (score 2):

So this is an arbitrary choice. Any $f(x,t)=f(x-vt)$ moves towards the $+x$-direction and this sets up an opposition where either space is positive and time is negative, or vice versa. And therefore one has to choose whether they want sine waves to look normal along the time axis but flipped along the space axis, or vice versa. This becomes even more poignant when we get into complex numbers, where we clearly want to have a positively rotating phasor $e^{ikx}$ or $e^{i\omega t}$ but you have to choose whether positivity is temporal or spatial. In fact, electrical engineers typically make the opposite choice from physicists, physicists are much more likely to write $e^{i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf x -\omega t)}$ whereas electrical engineers, perhaps conditioned by constantly seeing time traces on oscilloscopes, prefer to instead write $e^{j(\omega t-\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf x)}$. At least one of my courses suggested that we rectify this discrepancy simply by defining $j=-i$ and so this question also comes back to which square root of negative 1 we arbitrarily call $i$ and which $-i$, so that if you ask me for the place where this convention $e^{-i\omega t}$ is most ossified, has calcified into a rock which will never be broken, I would say quantum mechanics. Nobody is going to take the Schrodinger equation and swap out $i\hbar$ for $-i\hbar$ but it inevitably comes back as we divide by it and write $e^{-i E_nt/\hbar} |n\rangle.$

The $-i$ in the Fourier transform has the weight of objective truth behind it, you want the inverse to have $+i$ so that the $k$-space $\delta(k-k_0)$, a sort of infinitely tall infinitely skinny bell curve centered at wavenumber $k_0$, corresponds to the space signal $e^{i k x}$. But the rest of this type of thing does not have that weight.

Your two expressions are related by $A\mapsto -A$ or if you prefer $\phi\mapsto \phi\pm \pi.$ Neither choice can be argued as objectively more correct than the other.